# Extract the digits and append it in a different cell?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to automatically RegExp(extract) the digits(**AREA number**) in Column 3 combined with the Text 'A' to append in Column 1 **Date INDEX**.

The problem is I'm not yet familiar in using google sheets app-scripts.
Tried looking for solutions with similar situation as me, but to no avail.
I don't know to put VBA to app-scripts.

Tried using some codes.
I still can't seem to make it work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you if you can help me out. Thanks.

EDIT:
The scenarios is in the office i cant make column for the formula.
It must be "behind the scene".

[My googlesheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_gzKz2BqjzzFxjTr2skHUjbcNJOzogZXUTeCX-OVJSI/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: In Column 3 append to Column 1 with 'A' and extracted digits]

```
//NOT WORKING code

function onEdit(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var area=sh.getName();
  var regExp = new RegExp("\d*");  // Extract the digits
  var dataIndex = regExp.exec(area)[1];
  if(rg.columnStart==3) {  // Observe column 3
    var vA=rg.getValues();
    for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
      if(vA[i][0]) {
        sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).appendText((dataIndex) +'A'); // append to column 1 with 'A' and extracted digits
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the frequency of and the trigger for this task?

Comment: `var vA=rg.getValues();`: Since the range is a single cell, the method should be `getValue()`

Comment: @AntonDementiev remarked on the inefficiency of `sh.getRange(rg.rowStart + i,1).appendText((dataIndex) +'A'); `. Which draws one's attention to the fact that your code is trying to loop through the discrete values of `vA`. even though `rg` is very likely to be a single cell (which would mean that vA is a single value). This would further explain why your code wasn't working, and begs the question of whether `onEdit` is the right trigger for this task.

Comment: @Tedinoz thanks I learned from you that [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) is for getting one single cell, while [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) Returns the rectangular grid of values for this range.

Comment: @Tedinoz apologies for the butchered codes. I am still learning the terms and syntax used in google app-script. Currently understanding the [Difference between onEdit or onChange trigger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/119684/diference-between-onedit-or-onchange-trigger)

Comment: Might I ask... once you get beyond rows 0-9, what is the format of the standard? Do you keep a leading zero on the row number, or do you drop the leading zero?

Comment: Only the single digit 1-9 has leading zero..
Example:
20191201-01 to 20191201-500

Comment: "Currently understanding the Difference between onEdit or onChange trigger". I think that `onEdit` is probably the right choice in this instance. While `onChange` is triggered by "edit", it doesn't return the same event objects as `onEdit`. You can try them out and `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` will show you the event objects that each returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer extends your approach of using a script with an `OnEdit` trigger. But there are a number of differences between the two sets of code.

The most significant difference is that I have used the Javascript [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method (`var fields = value.split(' ');`) to get distinct values from the data entry.

Most of the other differences are error checking:

- `if(rg.columnStart === 3 && area === "work") {`: test for sheet="work" as well as an edit on Column C
- `var value = e.value.toUpperCase();`: anticipate that the test might be in lower case.
- `if (fields.length !=2){`: test that there are two elements in the data entry.
- `if (fields[0] != "AREA"){`: test that the first elment of the entry is the word 'area'
- `if (num !=0 && numtype ==="number"){`; test that the second element is a number, and that it is NOT zero.
- `if (colA.length !=0){`: test that Column A is not empty
- `var newColA = colA+"A"+num;`: construct the new value for Column A by using unary operator '+'.

---

```
function onEdit(e){

  // so5911459101

  // test for edit in column C and sheet = work

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;

  // get Event Objects
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var area=sh.getName();
  var row = rg.getRow();

  // test if the edit is in Column C of sheet = work
  if(rg.columnStart === 3 && area === "work") {  // Observe column 3 and sheet = work
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the edit is in Column C of 'Work'")

    // get the edited value
    var value = e.value.toUpperCase();
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the value = "+value+", length = "+value.length+", uppercase = "+value.toUpperCase());

    // use Javascript split on the value
    var fields = value.split(' ');
    //Logger.log(fields);//DEBUG
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: number of fields = "+fields.length)

    // test if there are two fields in the value
    if (fields.length !=2){
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the value doesn't have two fields")
    }
    else{
      // Logger.log("DEBUG: the value has two fields")

      // test if the first field = 'AREA'
      if (fields[0] != "AREA"){
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing because the value doesn't include area")

      }
      else{
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: do something because the value does include area")

        // get the second field - it should be a value
        var num = fields[1];
        num =+num
        var numtype = typeof num;
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: num= "+num+" type = "+numtype); //number


        // test type of second field
        if (num !=0 && numtype ==="number"){
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: the second field IS a number")

          // get the range for the cell in Column A
          var colARange = sh.getRange(row,1);
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: the ColA range = "+colARange.getA1Notation());

          // get the value of Column A
          var colA = colARange.getValue();
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: Col A = "+colA+", length = "+colA.length);

          // test if Column A is empty
          if (colA.length !=0){

            var newColA = colA+"A"+num;
            // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new cola = "+newColA);

            // update the value in Column A
            colARange.setValue(newColA);

          }
          else{

            // Logger.log("DEBUG: do nothing because column A is empty")

          }

        }
        else{
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: the second field isn't a number")
        }

      }

    }

  } 
  else{
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the edit is NOT in Column C of 'Work'")

  }

}
```

---

**REVISION**

If the value in Column C is sourced from data validation, then no need for and testing except that the edit was in Column C and the sheet = "work".

Included two additional lines of code:

`var colAfields = colA.split('-');`

`var colAdate = colAfields[0];`

This has the effect of excluding any existing characters after the hyphen, and re-establishing the hyphen, row number plus "A" and the AREA numeral.

---

```
function onEdit(e){

  // so5911459101 revised
  // only one test - check for ColumnC and sheet="work"

  // test for edit in column C and sheet = work

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet;

  // get Event Objects
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  var area=sh.getName();
  var row = rg.getRow();

  // test if the edit is in Column C of sheet = work
  if(rg.columnStart === 3 && area === "work") {  // Observe column 3 and sheet = work
    Logger.log("DEBUG: the edit is in Column C of 'Work'")

    // get the edited value
    var value = e.value
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: the value = "+value+", length = "+value.length);

    // use Javascript split on the value
    var fields = value.split(' ');
    //Logger.log(fields);//DEBUG

    // get the second field - it should be a value
    var num = fields[1];

    // get the range for the cell in Column A
    var colARange = sh.getRange(row,1);
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the ColA range = "+colARange.getA1Notation());

    // get the value of Column A
    var colA = colARange.getValue();
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Col A = "+colA+", length = "+colA.length);

    // use Javascript split on Column A in case of existing value
    var colAfields = colA.split('-');
    var colAdate = colAfields[0];

    // build new value
    var newColA = colAdate+"-"+row+"A"+num;
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: the new cola = "+newColA);

    // update the value in Column A
    colARange.setValue(newColA);

  } 
  else{
    Logger.log("DEBUG: the edit is NOT in Column C of 'Work'")

  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not say In column C was a dropdown list.
When I changed the value for Column C, it just continues adding the new value to the Date INDEX. How can you clear the previous and replace it with the correct Value in Column C.

Column A:20191129-05A231A123A75                                          
Column C: AREA 75

Comment: When you copy & pasted the AREA number. The suffix is not generated.
[My google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ir8rt-iBXFoINgjb6VVAsJ8KpnACM7zu8y1pPVeUTWI/edit#gid=1356182042)

Comment: @DeskDespair refer revision

Comment: @DeskDespair `onEdit` responses to a copy/paste, but the Event Objects for "value" and "oldValue" are NOT tracked. Shouldn't be a problem if you are using dropdowns.

Comment: "Tracked" = not a good word; "available" = better. You are using [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) - e.g. ` var rg=e.range;`. Put `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` in your code to view **all** the objects and values returned after each execution of the code. (Spoiler Alert:  you will see some undocumented objects!). In any event, the documentation shows that "onEdit" includes two objects "value" and "oldValue", but when the event is triggered by "copy/paste", "value" and "oldValue" are not included in the available objects.

Comment: Thank you @Tedinoz your code is well thought out and well documented. I figure out the